# Triple X's in URLs cause the question be Inaccessible for people like me

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'm from Iran. In my country the government filters web content; I'm not going to discuss that. They block any content contains triple `x` (of course if appears in this way `xxx`).

The `xxx` in page content is not the problem, as you know the question's title is the question's URL too, and problem is in the URL not the page content. There is no problem with `xxxxxx`, `xxx-something`, `xxxSomething`, the problem is just for `SPACExxxSPACE`.

If triple `x` is replaced with with something like `xyz` it would be be better for people like me. It would not change the question itself, just the URL.

**Update**

---

Some guys mentioned there is some problem with database, SVN & ..., if the stack's team update old questions! (btw, I'm using database, SVN too, and as I know it's not really problem with updating database, I'm doing that every day), anyway, replacing question can happen for future questions.

**OR**

In the right side hint box (you can see that when you going to ask question), **stack's team can suggest people to avoid using `xxx` in question title.**

Comment: Maybe users read this and use `xyz` instead of `xxx` in future, I think is not big deal using `xyz` instead of `xxx`.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I assume there're many more words that are blocked by Iran and other governments, do you suggest SE should replace them as well? What if that would change the meaning or formatting of posts?

Comment: I think if stack is for everyone, so maybe must try to fix the issues as much as possible.

Comment: On posts tagged [tag:feature-request], voting typically indicate agreement or disagreement with the proposed change.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Sure, but put the shoe on the other foot. You're asking us to inconvenience *all* of our users simply because one government has a silly word filter? This would only irritate a lot more users than are currently being affected.

Comment: @animuson because some governments are silly, some guys must miss some questions and articles because `xxx`?is not funny? I'm saying replacing `xxx` with something else is not impossible work

Comment: We get your point, Mehdi, and as said I'm sure you have the sympathy of everyone here. One could also make the argument that allowing access for people in countries with silly governments outweighs some effort on SO's part, and even inconveniencing everyone else *to some degree*. But it's not as simple a thing as you make it look. I can't speak for the SO team, but this is probably not going to happen.

Comment: Also, I just checked and realized the problem is *exceedingly small*. I can find [1,869 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Axxx) that you might have trouble accessing - out of more than 12 million.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The only option we have to do stuff like that is the blacklist filter, which adds another regex pass to every single thing that gets posted to the site. We only ever add things to that when it's absolutely necessary, and remove things that rarely ever get hit.

Comment: I just added some more info to my post. also I'm programmer too and I think it's really simple job.

Comment: Looking at the microscopic size of the problem, maybe there's a better solution: how about we edit it out of the titles of those questions that have loads of votes/views, and where it's used as a pure placeholder, when needed. The [TortoiseSVN question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn) (at the moment the highest voted question containing the string) is a good example.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani You don't really know the dynamics behind how SO is built and how it works, or you wouldn't be saying that this would be "a really simple job". The guys at SO are constantly weary about performance, and the entire site is a quite complex construct of stuff on a strictly as-necessary basis.

Comment: So left old questions and make that happen for upcoming questions

Comment: I edited your example question so you can access it.

Comment: @Mehdi, completely off-topic, but your avatar is derived from the Firefox logo, which is trademarked by the Mozilla foundation. Can you replace it in order to avoid breaking [the rules](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/identity/firefox/branding/)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi wouldn't that be between the Mozilla foundation and him, though? Not our concern really, as far as I can see

Comment: @Pekka, absolutely. I was just pointing that out in case they run into problems about that in the future.

Comment: Hmm, notable how the conviction that what's good for *some* people needs to be applied to *all* people is not just your government's problem.  Western sensibilities apply here of course.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think it's different with Firefox's logo, of course because I love Firefox I used the logo, but I'll search about that and if necessary I'll replace that, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

While I'm sure you have the sympathy of all of us here, I don't think Stack Overflow can start altering content for everyone sitting behind some form of government or other firewall.

- This would likely not be the only string that needs to be altered, so there'd be an unknowable number of future changes and updates.
- Each replaced string would likely create loads of problems as a consequence—broken code, changed meanings, confused users, et cetera.

Stack Overflow is indeed for everyone, but that's a [negative right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_and_positive_rights)—meaning, the site is not doing anything to actively prevent anyone from using it (like country filters, subscriptions, requiring participation to view content, paywalls, etc.).

It can not, however, fix every problem accessing the site that it hasn't caused.

**Edit:** the problem also appears to be very limited in size. I count [1,869 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3Axxx) on Stack Overflow, out of some 12 million. There might be a better way to work that out: we could manually edit the string out of question titles when needed, when they clearly do not serve any purpose other than being a placeholder. Whether there's a way to come up with a process for that would merit a different question, though.

Comment: You right, you should not replacing all filtered words, but it's `xxx` guys, it's not a big deal.

Comment: @Mehdi it *is* a big deal. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452353/android-xxx-hdpi-real-devices) is an example of a question where the filter would actually break code, and the meaning of the question.

Comment: True, that question is not blocked for me, because is not ` xxx `

Comment: OK - so the filter catches only when the string occurs in a whole word. But there's going to be questions out there that would get broken by the change, and we have no way of finding them in the thousands of questions that use the string as a placeholder. If this were as easy as you think, and came with no problems in the future, I'm sure the team would consider it. It's not, though.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4506060/2301450)'s another one. *Both* xxx and xyz are present on the page, replacing just xxx will introduce confusion.

Comment: @vaultah There problem is for `Title` not question body, also if we hav ` xxx `

Answer (score 7):

This would be a (reasonably concerning) slippery slope. I'm sure your government hasn't just blocked this sequence of words, but many others. Other governments (like China) might have a completly different set of blocked terms.

We can't start redacting content from the site when ever a government decides to be very silly and implement a keyword based web filter. Not to mention this would add the need to have people redact posts in bulk on stack overflow as reaction to pretty much any government changing their filters. Its not feasible or desireable.

> I think if stackovrflow is for everyone, must try to fix issues as
>   much as possible, down voter, please tell me, replacing xxx with xyz
>   will change the question concept?

Stack Overflow *is* for everyone in that it in and of itself doesn't prevent anyone from accessing it, besides some well-defined exceptions laid out in the ToS. It's not Stack Overflow's responsibility to ensure that your government in its censorship happy sillyness isn't blocking access to it's ressources.

Comment: You right, you should not replacing all filtered words, but it's `xxx` guys, it's not a big deal.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani If we accomodate Iran's "xxx" filter, someone from say china could reasonably demand we accomodate them too.

Comment: If you can help that guy, you should do that. I'm saying we are here to help each other as much as we can, right? I don't know, maybe I got something wrong about the reason of creating `stackoverflow`

Comment: yeah but then it's not a simple 1 word anymore but several 100 maybe if people from everywhere come and say "but @MehdiDehghani has gotten his word approved"

Comment: @Hayt I answered this before, please read comments before repeat other people's words. thanks.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I know this was brought up before but you seemed to ignore the point.

Comment: @Hayt I think you ignore the point, you (I mean all of you) just hit the down vote, without any reason, that's funny, it was just an offer. some guys with K scores think only they know about programming & ..., there is not really big for me, if I could n't open some questions, I think this is stack team problem if they can not solve this issue. of course if any of you was of stack core team.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Do you have a crystal ball? Votes are anonymous. I, for instance, didn't even vote on this question yet.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani this is a place for opinions and discussions. And most people here mentioned they can understand how it sucks etc. But this could have long term consequences just for making it easier for a minority here on the site + the questions you have a problem with are also just a minority. Of course it is easier for people who don't have the problem to say "no". But they may also easier see the bigger picture.

Comment: And in the end this is not a stackexchange problem but one of your government (which I understand is hard to change). But the people offered you to change those titles when you have problems. So if you ever run into one of those situations again I think you can post here and ask kindly for people to change the title for you.

Comment: The downvotes are BECAUSE people think it's a horrible idea. You offered it, and people showed you it's a bad idea with downvotes and then let you know WHY here. It's not a "simple" problem with a "simple" solution - it's not as simple as just replacing strings - you aren't thinking of all the ramifications.

Comment: Okay, you know more than me, you offer what can do about this issue?btw, it's not about me, it's about people like me. and also it's not really big deal for me, there is tons of ways to open that filtered pages, but I just wanna report the issue. your act reminded me what people did with Galileo, that's funny, but it's true. I just made an offer not a war !

Comment: @MehdiDehghani and what part of the answers you're getting here is "war" exactly? People are telling you why your offer isn't as good as you seem to believe it is, is all. I understand your logic for "the change isn't hard", because let's be honest, it isn't (or shouldn't, at least).... But that change sets the precedent we will filter out words based on a rule that isn't from us. This will make it hard to accommodate everyone at once, and creates a crazy slippery slope (check recent Meta discussions about offending content, you'll get an idea)

Comment: @Patrice xD, I said war, because of 21 down vote and so many negative comments, instead of offering a solution. btw I made an alternative way to my question body, I think that's not hard as updating questions.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani but, sorry if it sounds confrontational: Do we HAVE to offer a solution? You come in with a feature request, we say it's a bad one. Just like on the main site, the onus should be on you to tone, tweak, and polish your request, no? In any case. This is still not war. This is just people telling you they disagree with you. No one was rude, insulting or dismissive to you, so I don't even see why you say "negative comments"... Negative in the sense we disagree? sure. But besides that, there is a decently healthy conversation going on. What more can you ask for?

Comment: @Patrice of course you HAVE not offer a solution. but I could not find any try to solve the issue, people just comes hit the down vote, repeat some guys's words.anyway I just wanna help.it's funny, but they can cut the `Hi` from question, but they can not replace `xx` with `xy`.really interesting.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani well, there are a LOT of other considerations here. We have a reason to cut "hi" from messages (unecessary fluff). Cutting xxx because ONE country bans it.... means we inconvenience users for the problem of a country. This was said once. You didn't seem to consider this relevant. This is why everyone is repeating.  And yes there are reasons for not going with your FR

Comment: @Patrice first there is no need to CUT xxx, just replacing (for ex.) last x with something else, second you don't know, maybe there is more than one country, do you?and finally I ADDED another option to fix the issue, please take a look at the question.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani `because of 21 down vote and so many negative comments, instead of offering a solution.` I *did* offer a solution, one that could be implemented without changing the system at all, which you ignored. A concerted effort to edit the highest-voted and -viewed questions with an unnecessary "xxx" in the title would almost eliminate the problem. With 2000 rep, you can even do it yourself. And it's a very small problem anyway, affecting under 2,000 questions. If all of Iran were blocked from accessing Stack Overflow *at all* because of this, it would be a different discussion....

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, you right, I'm sorry, thanks to you, I'm saying that, there is multiple ways to deal with issue, I added new solution to my post too. but some guys comes and said NO. but as you said, there is a solution, as I said